# Como exportar dados de um banco de dados para um arquivo CSV?

Tags: python, angular, microsoft-excel, graphql

Olá, eu gostaria de saber como poderia ser feita a exportação de dados de um banco de dados para um planilha Excel, não necessariamente preciso de um código que faça isso, mas gostaria de saber quais linguagens podem ser usadas, onde posso encontrar essas informações e se seria possível por exemplo, pegar uma tabela de automoveis, e separar em mais planilhas dentro de um mesmo arquivo excel baseado em um tipo. Por exemplo: Dentro da tabela Automoveis no Banco de Dados existe a coluna tipo que pode ser preenchida com moto, carro, caminhão, onibus. Ao invés de juntar todos em uma unica planilha, separá-los dentro de um mesmo arquivo, ou seja, dentro do arquivo excel, existiriam 4 planilhas, uma para carro, outra para moto, outra para caminhão e uma última para onibus.

Estou desenvolvendo minha aplicação com Angular6 e GraphQL e utilizando alguns services em Python.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Qualquer linguagem resolve esse problema, só que falta mais detalhes pra resolver sua duvida.

Comment: @Tmilitino eu teria preferencia por python ou javascript, mas a duvida real é se é possível eu criar uma planilha para cada tipo de coluna na tabela em um mesmo arquivo excel. Eu nunca mexi com isso, então não faço ideia de como funciona. Resumindo, se existem 4 tipos em uma tabela do banco, seriam geradas 4 planilhas dentro um mesmo arquivo excel.

Comment: é possivel sim, dividir em 4 arquivos, do jeito que você quer. seu banco é sql? a consulta seria através de que?

Comment: Em Python, a biblioteca [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) é bastante utilizada para este tipo de tarefa. É possível ler csv, excel e sql para um dataframe em memória, modificá-lo e exportá-lo da forma como preferir, incluindo para diversas abas de um mesmo arquivo de excel. Mas claro que pandas não é a única ferramenta - e nem Python a única linguagem - existente para fazer isso.

Comment: @Tmilitino a ideia não seria 4 arquivos, mas sim, 1 arquivo contendo 4 abas, como dito pelo colega acima, dentro dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com qualquer linguagem você pode fazer isso! Se for para manter na mesma linha do desenvolvimento pode usar uma lib do python o `pandas` nela há uma funções que irá lhe ajudar nisso. Essa seria uma forma simples e rápida(desenvolvimento).

1- `read_sql` - conectar ao banco e extrair os

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql('select * from automovel", [parametros para conexão])
```

2- `to_excel` gravar em um arquivo excel

```
df.to_excel("saida.xlsx", index=False)
```

assim irá salvar toda a consulta em um único arquivo Excel.

Para fazer o que você quer de dividir por tipo de veiculo, você tem que que filtrar o dataframe pelo tipo e depois salvar em excel. Como você disse que não queria um código pronto, acredito que com isso consiga ter um norte. Caso não consiga diga que vou completando a resposta

Referencias

[read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-ocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

[to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)